# Change item height if it width is more than 500px - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an item on the page(500x200), and when its width is more than 500px, the height should be increased to 400.

Is it possible to be done with jQuery?

Comment: short answer: yes

Comment: Look at these for reference http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Look up CSS media queries before charging down the JS route.

Comment: With JQuery you can use the method [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) to know when a resize happend and then change the size of your element.

Comment: Not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use resize

```
  $( '#item' ).resize(function() {
     if($( '#item').width()>500)
    {
    $( '#item').height($( '#item').height()+400);
    } 
    });
```

Comment: I need to track item width, not the window

Comment: ok i update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with jquery you can do like given below:-

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 501px)").matches) {
                alert('this is working with only more than 500px width');
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

$('#myimage').width(500); // Units are assumed to be pixels
$('#myimage').height(400);

Comment: see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)